# how to create rescue initramfs image on centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, centos-7, initramfs-tools

After my last launch `yum update` my test box have `kernel-3.10.0-327.13.1` installed. While installing, dracut generated `initramfs-3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64.img`, but `initramfs-0-rescue-7da0bd6ff130413b99bf0b6a1bde637e.img` left old with `kernel-3.10.0-327`. How to generate new rescue initramfs image with new kernel and new kernel modules like zfs installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the rescue kernel and image are created by `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/51-dracut-rescue-postinst.sh` when a kernel is installed for the first time. This script checks for the presence of the rescue kernel and image and doesn't create new ones when additional kernels are installed.

To regenerate them, you'll need to move the existing ones out of the way:

```
mv /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-$(cat /etc/machine-id){,.backup}
mv /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-$(cat /etc/machine-id).img{,.backup}
```

Then you can then run the script like:

```
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/51-dracut-rescue-postinst.sh $(uname -r) /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: nice answer, another way:
`$ sudo rm /boot/*rescue*`
`$ sudo dnf reinstall kernel-core`